# Laravel join table using eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to load last 5 comments with related posts selecting only id and title from post.

In first case I decided get all columns from posts:

```
Comment::with(['post'])->take(5)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

And it's working fine.

But when I try get only two columns ("id, title") then nothing from posts is loaded.

```
Comment::with(['post:id,title'])->take($number)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

I did a test and when I removed "orderBy('id', 'desc')" then was fine again.

```
Comment::with(['post:id,title'])->take($number)->get();
```

So must be some problem with "orderBy" option.

Is it any way to fix it? It's mean get only selected columns from "posts" table and order results from the last one?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to clarify by what `id` you want to order. `id` of post or `id` of comment.

Comment: Why not getting the post by id and then getting all comments for it?

Comment: @MaihanNijat because task is to get __last comments__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As both your Comment and Post models contain `id`, Laravel doesn't know by which one do you want to sort. So, add a table name to your `orderBy`:

```
Comment::with(['post:id,title'])->take($number)->orderBy('comments.id', 'desc')->get();
```

Here `comments` is name of your table/entity, maybe it is `comment`.

Comment: Thank you. Now it is obvious for me :D.